# How to add rowheadercolumn (arrow on left) to Gridview In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, datagrid

I'm using a gridview control for an asp.net webforms application in Visual Studio 2010. I need to add the column on the left that has the little arrow ">" that selects a row. Here is a picture:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Paging_DataGridView/PagingDataGridView_scr.jpg

I have searched everywhere and cannot find it. I have seen help for this using a datagridview control but that control will only work on winforms and not on webforms. I have a copy of another program that uses a datagrid instead of a gridview and it has this "arrow on the left to select the row function" but I can't find how to turn it on or off.

Also should I be using a datagrid or a gridview. I was under the impression that gridviews were more modern and should be used where possible.

Thank You!

Comment: set the `DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = true;`

Comment: Display an arrow for selected row is not common in web application *although it is very common in Win From*. If you want, **CheckBox** might be a little bit user friendly.

Comment: It's not a DataGridView it's a GridView, there isn't a RowHeadersVisible option. Thanks! I think I'll have to live with the buttons provided.

Answer (score 0):

I will use [Bootstrap](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) and jQuery 3.1.1 in my example

But in this example you will use only the font-awesome css
*(I discovered this font-awesome using this bootstrap theme*
You can change the icon on `<i></i>` element changing the **'chevron-right'** on **'fa fa-chevron-right'** to other icon of your choice **'arrow-right'** for example. Look on **'font-awesome/less/icons.less'** file to choose the icon that suits you.

[image: font-awesome]

You can add jQuery to your project with `Pack Manage Concole` on VS:
`Install-Package jQuery -ProjectName SubjectC`

**ASPX**

```xml
<head>
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
.
.
.
<asp:GridView
    ID="gvPerson" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
    ItemType="MyObject"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="selectable-row" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="selectable-row" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="width> 30px;">
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RecordID" DataField="RecordID" SortExpression="RecordID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fname" DataField="NameFirst" SortExpression="NameFirst" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LName" DataField="LName" SortExpression="LName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
.
.
.
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("tr.selectable-row").on("click", function (event) {
            $('tr > td > div > i.fa').removeClass('fa-chevron-right');
            $(this).children('td')
                .first().children('div')
                .first().children('i')
                .first().addClass('fa fa-chevron-right');
        });
    });
</script>
```